# How to passe an array to jquery in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following code :

```
{% set aSessionKeys = app.session.get('aBasket')|keys  %}
onkeyup="calculatePrice({{ product['product_price'] }},{{ product['product_id'] }},{{ aSessionKeys }})
```

And I have an error :

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Can you help me please? Thx in advance. So exist a solution to passe this array?
I do like this :

```
{% set aKeys = aSessionKeys|join(',') %}
{{ dump(aKeys) }}
```

It shows good, but if I passe to jquery :

```
calculatePrice({{ product['product_price'] }},{{ product['product_id'] }},{{ aKeys }})
```

When I do in js methode calculatePrice() :

```
function calculatePrice(price, product_id, aKeys) {
        console.log(aKeys);
        var x = document.getElementById("product_quantity_"+product_id);
        var total_price = price * x.value;
        $("#total_price_"+product_id).html(total_price+" <small> MDL</small>");
        sum = 0;
        $("#total_price_basket").html();
    }
```

It shows only the first value of aKeys

Answer (score 0):

You have very popular error. You are trying to display array. But how do you imagine that? You can use `{{ dump(aSessionKeys) }}` for that purpose or use first element: `{{ aSessionKeys.0 }}` (if it is not an array or object).

But if you want to print all values from this array you can run foreach loop:

```
{% for element in aSessionKeys %}
    {# something here #}
    {{ element }}
    {# something here #}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously (as you are using the `|keys` filter) `aSessionKeys` contains an array, and by using `{{ aSessionKeys }}` in the template Twig will try to output the array as a string, which doesn’t work (or at least is not what you want).

To convert the array to a string, you should use Twig’s `join()` filter, which will concatenate the array values using a given delimiter string. So, if – for instance – you want to join the values using a comma, this would be the code:

`{{ aSessionKeys|join(',) }}`

Comment: It’s hard to identify the problem without knowing the actual content of the array. But in any case: if you `join()` the array keys using a non-number, you have to enclose it in quotes. And if the problem persists after changing that, it would be good to know how the `calculatePrice({{ product['product_price'] }},{{ product['product_id'] }},{{ aKeys }})` is actually rendered in the HTML source.